# Webgpu shows scripting in Idle state

Tags: webgpu

I've been tinkering with WebGPU and, when profiling the page on a couple different pages, I see that the script is marked as Idle. This makes it hard to estimate the actual rendering budget, as the time that the JS is executing is actually quite small but it looks much larger due to the Idle marking. Is there anyway to clear up this Idle when using WebGPU? Thanks!

[image: Idle state in Austin Eng example]
[image: Idle state in my own example]